# Async & Await using arguments (callbacks)

Tags: javascript

I found I code snippet in W3Schools.com ([visit site](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_async2)). It works fine, but according Promise syntax, if there is failure (error) we have to use myReject. I have been changed from myResolve to myReject. It has not worked. What is the point?

```js
async function getFile() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        myResolve(req.response);
      } else {
        myResolve("File not Found"); //It should to be myReject.
      }
    };
    req.send();
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = await myPromise;
}

getFile();
```

Comment: *It has not worked.* what not work?

Comment: Why not use `fetch`? What are you expecting and what actually happens?

Comment: reject return Promise with null，u should catch the error that you reject

Comment: When error appears myReject generates error message in Promise syntax. In this code snippet is using  "myResolve("File not Found");". Its work fine. But I try to change it to "myReject("File not Found");", it does not generate error message. Why does not it work?

Comment: @darionas it's the opposite, the code with two myResolve actually *treat error as success* which is not good, at this point it's no better (probably worse) than write those `innerHTML` line directly in `Promise` body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise reject (in this case, `myReject`) is like throwing an error in a function.

`await` is basically calling the promise and waiting for the response.

To catch an error, we can use a `try...catch` block for async/await functions:

```
async function getFile() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status === 200) {
       myResolve(req.response);
      } else {
        myReject("File not Found"); //Changed to myReject.
      }
    };
    req.send();
  });
  try {
    const response = await myPromise;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response;
  }
  catch(error){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "An error occurred: " + error;
  }
}
getFile();
```

In addition, you can call re-write the code to have `getFile` handle the error:

```
async function getFile() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status === 200) {
       myResolve(req.response);
      } else {
        myReject("File not Found"); //Changed to myReject.
      }
    };
    req.send();
  });
  return await myPromise;
}
getFile().then(function(response){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response;
}).catch(function(error){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "An error occurred: " + error;
});
```

More reading on async/await: https://javascript.info/async-await

Also, like Francesco Lisandro said: a server can return different OK responses other than `200`.

For simplicity, sure we can use `req.status`, but we can also use `req.statusText` that *should* give us "OK" if the response is OK.

Comment: prefer triple equal in javascript code for equality checking

Comment: @Shikamu yes, that too.  I was just copy-pasting the code, but I can always edit that.

Funny enough, I came across someone's answer and saw that and thought that too. IDK why I didn't edit mine then, IG I just forgot.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to to reject your promise in case file is not found which you have already figured out how to do. Now, a promise being rejected is an exception which we need to handle here.

```
async function getFile() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        myResolve(req.response);
      } else {
        myReject("File not Found");
      }
    };
    req.send();
  });
  try{
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = await myPromise;
  } catch(e){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I got an error" ;
  }
}

getFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in that case, the error can be different from File `Not Found` (status code is `404`). Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status. Additionally you need a way to separate success cases to error cases and that's why you can use it. In your case you can use `reject` but you should then use `.catch()` to handle the error when you call `getFile()`.

```
async function getFile() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        myResolve(req.response);
      } else {
        myReject("File not Found");
      }
    };
    req.send();
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = await myPromise;
}


getFile().catch((e)=>console.log(e));
```